# git clone svn to split folders into separate git repositories

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have some old dump of a SVN repo with a straightforward structure:

```
trunk/src/
  folder1/
  folder2/
  folder3/
  ...
```

I know that each `folder` is in fact a separate project, so I would like to clone this svn repo into git but splitting each `folder` into separate git repository and preserving history. How can I do that?

I don't need magic loop-scripts. I can name each folder manually. I would only like to know how to clone specific folder from svn into new git repository preserving history.

**[Update]**

I have only a dump of SVN repo, no SVN server. So I cant do

`git svn clone svn://path/to/my/trunk/src/folder1`

Instead I'm using

`git svn clone file://path/to/my/dump`

**[What I tried]**

I've used `svnadmin` to create a svn dump file, then used `svndumpfilter` to filter out only folders that I need. I managed to split the original svn dump into separate files, one for each `folder`.

```
svnadmin dump /svn/old_repos > ./repository.dump
svndumpfilter include /trunk/scr/folder1
      --drop-empty-revs
      --renumber-revs
      --preserve-revprops
    < ./repository.dump > ./folder1.dump
```

I tried to use `git svn clone file:///path/to/my/folder1.dump` but I got this error:

```
Couldn't open a repository:
    Unable to open an ra_local session to URL:
        Unable to open repository `file://path/to/my/filtered/dump/folder1.dump`
           at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 2143
```

This looks like the dump file is corrupted. I tried `svndump load /repos/folder1 < /path/to/my/folder1.dump` but I got another error, this time from svnadmin:

```
svnadmin: File not found: transaction `0-0`, path `trunk/src/folder1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Dump of SVN repo? As in `svnadmin dump`? When I had that problem, I set up temporary local SVN repository, imported the dump there, then ran `git svn clone`.

Comment: @Vi. Dump of SVN repo - as in `cp -r /path/to/repo/root /some/other/place` :)

Comment: So try to check out (or print info `svn info`) of the directory you want to clone using usual Subversion tools, then, when you figure our the correct path syntax, insert it into `git svn clone`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what did the trick for me:

1. Create a svn repository dump file for later processing:

   `svnadmin dump /svn/old_repo > /tmp/svn/repository.dump`
2. Use `svndumpfilter` to split dump file into separate dumps:

   `svndumpfilter include /trunk/scr/folder1
     --drop-empty-revs
     --renumber-revs
     --preserve-revprops
   < /tmp/svn/repository.dump > /tmp/svn/dump/folder1.dump`
3. Create new empty svn repository

   `svnadmin create /tmp/svn/repos/folder1`
4. Create root dir insde new empty svn repository. This is very important! I missed that step and almost gone mad due to some unclear svnadmin erros:

   `svn mkdir file:///tmp/svn/repos/folder1/trunk/src/folder1 --parents -m "Go"`
5. Load new dump into empty svn repository:

   `svnadmin load /tmp/svn/repos/folder1 < /tmp/svn/dump/folder1.dump`
6. Now some git magic. Note the `-T` arg - it's very handy. I used this to make my life easier and make `folder1` a root for git repo. If I didn't do that, I'd end up with a git repo structure like this: `trunk/src/folder1/*` (that is what I had initially in my svn repo). And I wanted to just have the `folder1` as a root:

   `git svn clone -T /trunk/src/folder1 file:///tmp/svn/repos/folder1 /new/path/folder1`

And that was it. Steps 2-7 repeat for each directory for which you want to have a new git repository. I ended up writing a simple script for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
git svn clone svn://path/to/your/trunk/src/folder1
```

?

Subversion directories are usually considered as a sort of repositories on themselves.

Note that there will be no SVN branch and tag integration in this case.

In case of a dump you probably need to import it somewhere (into a temporarly local SVN repository, for example).

Comment: There are no branches, so this is not a problem. The problem is that I have SVN dump only. No actual SVN server, so I use `git svn clone file://.....`. I edited my question to explain that.